# Show a TextView in front of a VideoView?

Tags: android, user-interface, widget

Is there a way to show a `TextView` in front of a `VideoView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stack widgets on the Z-axis using `RelativeLayout`. Have your `VideoView` be the first child of the `RelativeLayout`. Have your `TextView` be the second child. Have their `android:layout_` rules set up such that they overlap in the X/Y coordinate plane. The `TextView` will appear to float over the `VideoView`.

Comment: In addiction to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If a [Custom Toast](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) is not enough you can try with a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Comment: the toast would help if it could be completely transparent, showing just the text, and I could show 2 at a time. The transparency part looks like it is possible.. I'm trying here..

Comment: I would like to show 2 of them, one in the top (on up key press), and one in the bottom (on down key press). They don't need to show at the same time. But Android dont let me use 2 toasts. When I tried using the same, just reseting the position and text, it works well, but if I press both keys in short time, both the informations will be shown in bottom or top, where it first appear. Any idea to solve this? Was I clear?