# What controls the order of view's appearing on the screen on the UI?

Tags: java, android, view

I have an app with a layout using the following view objects.  2 spinners, 2 buttons, 1 seekbar and a custom view object that is basically a canvas I draw to.

For some reason the spinners and seekbar are drawn on top of the canvas, but the 2 buttons are not.  I'm confused as to why this is.

So, how is this ordered determined?

Thanks.

Edit: XML at request (this is before I moved the customview to the top which fixes the problem).  If the order is supposed to be XML based then the custom view should have covered the spinners which it did not.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cc_component"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/cc_component_spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:text="@string/step1_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switch_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <com.cmllc.zcc.CCView
        android:id="@+id/cc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switch_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rightarrow1" /> 

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/component_color"
        android:layout_above="@+id/switch_color"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/component_color_spinner" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/switch_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:minWidth="200dip"
        android:progress="50"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you could show your layout file's code here... I might be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be the order in which they are added to the view. Other than that you can use `View.bringChildToFront()`.

See this post: [Defining Z order of views of RelativeLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android)

And in a [post here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4877e96f824205ad) by Dianne Hackborn, an Android Developer at Google, she indicates the same thing regarding z-order behavior.

I implemented your layout, or as closely as I could without all of your resources and custom `View` object, and I get the results I except. The first spinner, textview, and button appear underneath the custom object, which I am imitating with the following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#880000FF" />
```

I then see the second button, second spinner, and seekbar on top. Are you doing anything weird with your custom view? That or perhaps it is something happening due to later manipulation of your views.

Edit: I double checked and I do indeed see the display as I describe above

Comment: Alright, I moved my custom view inside the XML file and while it did solve my problem, I'm still confused.  If the XML file is the master, then the spinners should have been covered by my custom view (Canvas) since they were defined in XML before the custom view.

Comment: I'm unsure about that specific situation. If you post the relevant source code we may be able to better determine why precisely you were getting the result you were.

Comment: Are you messing with any of their layout related settings in code, or is that pretty much all you're doing with them right now? Also, is that the version that gives you the undesired result?

Comment: @user432209 Works as expected for me, see above.

Comment: I am not messing with much in code...just a View.GONE or View.VISIBLE here or there.  Since your getting different results without the custom view that tells me the problem is either my code in the custom view or just the way Android interprets it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm going to double check it once more when I get home. Regardless, it isn't a huge deal as you can get your desired result by moving your custom view to being the first item. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting any of your views relative to any others. In a relative layout, you need to tell the view that your views are above, below, etc other views. You need to give them relative settings, not just align_parent on a few of them.

Comment: Relative settings (or lack thereof) do not impact a draw order from what I've learned in the past 12 hours.

Comment: Umm, I guess it depends on what you mean draw order. I assumed he meant that his views were piling on top of each other