# I want to bring button(subview) to front in android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/topHeader"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


      <!-- Header aligned to top -->
    <!--   <include layout="@layout/header_layout" /> -->

      <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <!--   <include layout="@layout/footer_layout" /> -->

      <!-- Content below header and above footer -->
    <!--   <include layout="@layout/intermediate_layout" /> -->
      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />
      </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**I make layout xml, in which I put one button in center.And I want that button to front always.
        I adding some textview, imageview etc dynamically on this layout and that one centerised button should be bring front.
        This is possible in ios and i want in android.Any suggestion for this thoughts?
    I have above topHeaderlayout.xml** 
**In this xml, I dynamically adds view.And one button should be front of view.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use **bringToFront** method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). Also please read this — [Defining Z order of views of RelativeLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android). I think this should help.

Answer (score 4):

To both summarize and yet clarify:

```
yourView.bringToFront();
```