# Android Set position of an element below fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, position

I have a `RelativeLayout` activity. I have another layout for a fragment. The fragment layout is added programmatically to the activity. In the `RelativeLayout` of the activity there is a `LinearLayout` with three buttons. How can I set the position of this `LinearLayout` to be under(in y edge) the fragment without having the fragment in the activity xml?

This is the activity XML structure:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    <LinearLayout
         >

        <Button
             />

        <Button
            />

        <Button
            />
    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bring to front your layout this post could helps you:
 [Defining Z order of views of RelativeLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android)

and android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()

Comment: thank you for your response!
which layout are you talking about?

Comment: The layout that you wanted to be in front (The layout that have three buttons I think), if it doesnt works use FrameLayout instead RelativeLayout.

Comment: Everything is messing up if I change the RelativeLayout to a FrameLayout. Also I can see the LinearLayout with the buttons, I just can't move it to be below my fragment.

Comment: when you refeer "be under" you mean in y or z edge?