# Android bring view in front of overlay relative layout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have a Relative layout with 5 buttons on the bottom. When you click and hold on one of these buttons it makes another invisible relative layout visible which overlays the whole screen. I want the button that was clicked to make the overlay visible to remain visible with the overlaying relative layout. How can i do this?

I have tried using button.BringToFront along with invalidate, but that did not work. The button was still behind the overlay.

Comment: Separate your layouts. The buttons on a layout on the bottom and just over them the swapping layouts.

Comment: You start doing it by ordering views in the XML file,  lower in the XML file means higher in the Z axis, then, you can move your button to the from programmatically with btn.bringToFront(); You will find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they were very helpful. Could the down voters care to comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the overlay in front of the button that I wanted to remain visible. The trick was just XML organization.