# Setting "z-index" on LinearLayout on android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am placing four image views on a vertical linear layout. I want them to ocuppy the same space, so I assign to each an `android:layout_weight="1"`. I also want them to overlap (that is a design requeriment), so I set a negative margin for each view. The last image I add (`@+id/floor_1st`) is the last to be added (the one at the bottom), so it stays at the front. However, I want it to be the other way around: I want the first image on layout to be at the front followed by the second and so on (the last image shuld be at the back).

I understand that it is easier to control the order the images are placed using a `RelativeLayout`, but I do not know how to place the images the way I want using this layout. I have also seen that is possible to use the method `bringToFront()`, but that just do not let the images to overlap.

So, is there any way to place the images in the order I want using `LinearLayout`? Or should I use another layout? In this case, how should I place the images?

Here is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/floors_container"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/overview_buttons_top_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/overview_buttons_bottom_margin"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/floor_4th"
        android:src="@drawable/piso_4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floors_overview_margin_three_quarter"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/floor_3rd"
        android:src="@drawable/piso_3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/floors_overview_margin_quarter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floors_overview_margin_half"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/floor_2nd"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/piso_2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/floors_overview_margin_half"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floors_overview_margin_quarter"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/floor_1st"
        android:src="@drawable/piso_1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/floors_overview_margin_three_quarter"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Provide a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation to each `ImageView`

Comment: And then how I control the "z-index"?

Comment: For z-index you can set margin from top in negative form like `marginTop="-20dp"`

Comment: That is what I am currently doing. The margin top/bottom I define are negative values.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to reverse drawing order, you need to subclass the LinearLayout class and override getChildDrawingOrder.

```
@Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
    //The standard implementation just retuns i
    return childCount - i - 1;
}
```

Make sure to enable custom ordering somewhere:

```
setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

For Android from Level 21, you can use view.setZ() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing

For Android level below 21, I suggest to use either FrameLayout or RelativeLayout combine with bringToFront() and/or negative padding, margin if required. For using of bringToFront() method, refer to this [Defining Z order of views of RelativeLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

For achieving this kind of layout FrameLayout would be your best bet.

This layout is generally used for z-Index based structure(overlapping). Take a look about this class here :- [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) .

And here is one link which shows its use :- [Example Given.](http://javatechig.com/android/android-framelayout-example)

You can find other links too demonstrating its use.

Hope it helps,

Thanks.