# Bypassing stacked views with click listeners

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-viewpager, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout with both an ImageView and a ViewPager. It seems as though the ViewPager sits on top of the ImageView because I had an onClick listener set up for my ImageView and when I implemented the ViewPager the ImageView no longer responds to clicks. Is there any way to "click through" to the ImageView below? In general, is it possible to ignore the "top" view and allow the "bottom" view to respond to click events?

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/feed_image_content_description"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />        

         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/custom_viewpagertitlestrip"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Relevant question about `z-index` in `RelativeLayout`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614393/defining-z-order-of-views-of-relativelayout-in-android

Comment: I guess I could also just move the click event to the layer with the highest z-index...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try to tell ViewPage (and its children) they are not clickable by setting layout attribute `android:clickable="false"` (I'd also perhapss set `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` from XML or call `setClickable(false)` from code.