# How to put a ProgressBar ontop of a View

Tags: android, layout, view, progress-bar

I am trying to put a `ProgressBar` on top of a `View` in my Layout, 
I have looked for a solution but couldn't find one online, 
is there a way for me to achieve that outcome ?

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#dedede"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities.Testings_Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_testings_">



    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Testings_screen_mainHeadline"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mainWhiteView2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mainWhiteView3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Return to Main Menu"
        android:id="@+id/Testings_screen_returnToMainMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/Testings_screen_mainHeadline"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:progress="40"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mainWhiteView" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

It is suppose to show the `ProgressBar` but it doesn't. 
Does someone know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `elevation` to the `ProgressBar` element, try this:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:progress="40"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainWhiteView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mainWhiteView"
    android:elevation="10dp" />
```

check also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38536318/3608785) for additional informations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dedede"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities.Testings_Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_testings_">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:progress="40" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Testings_screen_mainHeadline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Testings_screen_mainHeadline"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/mainWhiteView2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/mainWhiteView3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainWhiteView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Testings_screen_returnToMainMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Return to Main Menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```