# Android Relativelayout, views don't overlay buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to implement simple view overlay using RelativeLayout but it seems like something is wrong, I want the last view in the layout to be rendered on top of the rest but it is actually rendered behind. can you spot whats wrong in my code?

edit: figured out it only happens if I want to overlay buttons with some other view

[image]

here is the view xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="Normal View"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and of course you did tried to do internet search with "RelativeLayout z order"

Comment: Reverse order between Button & FrameLayout in your xml

Comment: @Selvin yeah, I know that the lower the view is defined in the layout the higher the z order that's why I expect the framelayout to be rendered on top of the button, not the other way around.

Comment: @Tonteria24 that didn't work either

Comment: there is  (Daniel Wilson's) explanation in the first link what is going on some API

Comment: ok, i was wrong but now try this: set android:elevation="0dp" for the Button.

Comment: @Selvin that explains it but offers no solution, as others might have this question as well, guess it is appropriate to keep this question and find the optimal solution/workaround

ps. I edited my question

Comment: @Tonteria24 not even that :D

Comment: Setting elevation is not working?

Comment: nop............

Comment: @Selvin can you please remove your downvote and upvote instead so it gets some attention?

Answer (score 1):

buttons and other elements in API 21 and greater have a high elevation, and therefore ignore the xml order of elements regardless of parent layout. thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39572923/325306) answer.

The solution to this bug is to set a higher elevation on the view which I want to be rendered over the button, the elevation value for the overlaying view should be higher than the button's.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            view.setElevation(1000);
}
```

or in xml

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:elevation="1000"
...
```